# Grep ip's and hostnames from a Mirc log

Tags: regex, unix, filter, mirc

I need to filter out all of the hostnames / ip's that have joined my server.

I have a log file, but I don't know what regex I could use, I have already tried searching here.

Maybe you can help me out?

Log:

```
03[22:56] * Jason (~Jason@33-33-33-33.rev.sfr.net) has joined #talk
03[22:56] * NotJason (~NotJason@12.34.22.22) has joined #talk
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What does the log look like, and what output are you looking for?

Comment: Log looks like this:
03[22:56] * Jason (~Jason@33-33-33-33.rev.sfr.net) has joined #talk
03[22:56] * NotJason (~NotJason@12.34.22.22) has joined #talk
I tried filtering the ip's, that worked. but now I need the hostnames

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you should try this:

```
(?<=@).+?(?=\))
```

`.`  matches any character

`+`  one or more time

`?`  make it non greedy i.e search will stop at first occurence

`?=` positive lookahead(look for `)` and stop)

Update:

With grep it will be like this

```
grep -o -P  '(?<=@)(.+?)(?=\))' logfile > file2
```

`?<=` is positive look behind(look for @ behind).

`-o` will print only matched part.

`-P` perl-regexp(PATTERN is a Perl regular expression)

Comment: I feel pretty dumb.. But how can  I use this in grep?
I've tried "grep -E "@.+?(?=\))" file > file2" But that didn't do the job..

Comment: Thanks, this did the job.

Answer (score 0):

Do you allow parenthesis in nicknames?
If no, you can try something like

```
$ cat logfile | grep -o \(.*\) | tr -d '()'
```

If yes, you'll need to tell us more about what nicknames can be and what chat room names can be. Otherwise, all provided regexps here might miss some cases when either nickname or room name contain spaces or ( ).

Comment: I do not need the nicknames (:, only what comes after @ and what closes with a ). the content of what that is doesn't matter, as long as it's filtered. Your command by the way gives me this error: 
$: command not found

Comment: Ok. Try to type this into your terminal:
`cat logfile | grep -o @.*\) | tr -d '@)'`
`logfile` should be a path to your logfile, e.g. `/var/logs/my_logfile`